# How to disable cursor pointer in Desktop Duplication API

Tags: directx, dxgi, desktop-duplication

I am working with this solution [DXGI desktop duplication sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Desktop-Duplication-Sample-da4c696a/view/Discussions) its fine for capturing single monitor but when I do extended monitor (below image : enable extended monitor) the mouse cursor is embedded with captured image. This issue is coming only during in extend enable.

actually `AcquireNextFrame` API will return image buffer(DesktopResource) and FrameInfo, DesktopResource don't have cursor image we draw cursor by programmatically using FrameInfo(cursor coordinates) but here I disabled draw mouse pointer but even though am getting cursor pointer on image.

How can I disable cursor on image during in extend.

[image]